# Fastest way to take a screenshot with python on windows

Tags: python, windows, screenshot

What's the fastest way to take a screenshot on windows? `PIL.ImageGrab` is rather slow.. it takes between 4-5 seconds to take 30 screenshots of the same small window. Taking screenshots of the whole desktop is even slower.

Comment: Sound like what you realy want are screen videos, a la CamStudio on Sourceforge. What's the use case?

Comment: to get the highest score ever on [winterbells](http://www.ferryhalim.com/orisinal/g3/bells.htm) =P

Comment: Just gave Winterbells a play and it's surprisingly addicting

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use win32 APIs directly .

1. First give the focus to the App that you want to take screenshot of.
   [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080719/screenshot-an-application-in-python-regardless-of-whats-in-front-of-it)
2. [Win32 API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) can help with the screenshot:

```py
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con

w = 1920 # set this
h = 1080 # set this
bmpfilenamename = "out.bmp" #set this

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, windowname)
wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, bmpfilenamename)

# Free Resources
dcObj.DeleteDC()
cDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
```

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT, as this recently bit me in the ass: you HAVE TO delete/release all the DCs created by this, or after taking ~90 images, you won't be able to anymore. in this case, `dcObj.DeleteDC(); cDC.DeleteDC(); win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)`

Comment: See this script for more details: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/576924-win32ui-vs-wxpy-screen-capture-multi-monitor

Comment: As a followup from @Claudiu's comment (which is indeed necessary as he notes), I found `win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())` also necessary.  I've edited the answer to include both comments.

Comment: This is SO much quicker than pyscreenshot and PIL thanks!

Comment: Where is `windowname` defined and/or what is it supposed to be?

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. If I create a DC object like this
`dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)`
I can't access the functions of that object, so `dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()` isn't working
(I use VSCode and it usually gives suggestions when typing a dot after an object, but here it doesn't do that so I'm thinking I need to import something else?

I installed pywin32 in my virtual environment and imported `win32gui, win32ui, win32con` in the program.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: To take a screenshot, yes. But in the case what you screenshot is a 3D rendered image, isn't it faster to grab the Framebuffer, instead of waiting that windows gets hold of it back?

Answer (score 6):

Just found out how to do it with gtk. Seems fastest by far:

```
def image_grab_gtk(window):
    left, top, right, bot = get_rect(window)
    w = right - left
    h = bot - top

    s = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(
        gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, w, h)

    s.get_from_drawable(
        gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window(),
        gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system(),
        left, top, 0, 0, w, h )

    final = Image.frombuffer(
        "RGB",
        (w, h),
        s.get_pixels(),
        "raw",
        "RGB",
        s.get_rowstride(), 1)
    return final
```

Without converting to a `PIL` Image, it's 8x faster than PIL on my test case. With converting, it's still ~2.7x faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my newly created project [DXcam](https://github.com/ra1nty/DXcam): I think for raw speed it's the fastest out there (in python, and without going too deep into the rabbit hole). It's originally created for a deep learning pipeline for FPS games where the higher FPS you get the better. Plus I (am trying to) design it to be user-friendly:
For a screenshot just do

```py
import dxcam
camera = dxcam.create()
frame = camera.grab()  # full screen
frame = camera.grab(region=(left, top, right, bottom))  # region
```

For screen capturing:

```py
camera.start(target_fps=60)  # threaded
for i in range(1000):
    image = camera.get_latest_frame()  # Will block until new frame available
camera.stop()
```

I copied the part of the benchmarks section from the readme:

|  | DXcam | python-mss | D3DShot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Average FPS | **238.79** | 75.87 | 118.36 |
| Std Dev | 1.25 | 0.5447 | 0.3224 |

The benchmarks is conducted through 5 trials on my 240hz monitor with a constant 240hz rendering rate synced w/the monitor (using blurbuster ufo test).

You can read more about the details here: https://github.com/ra1nty/DXcam

Comment: this is an interesting library! please get that on main PyPI. their testing repo is just for testing.

Comment: FWIW this was much slower than mss for my application, but the guarantee of every frame being new is nice.

Comment: Is there a way to grab screenshot from specific window through dxcam?

Answer (score 1):

You can use package [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html):

### Save screenshot to image file

```py
import mss

with mss.mss() as sct:
    filename = sct.shot(output="output.png")
```

### Get the numpy representation of screenshot

```
import mss
import numpy as np

with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 160, "left": 160, "width": 160, "height": 135}
    img_array = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    # Do whatever you want...
```

Comment: How fast is this compared to other options, if you checked? TY for sharing, regardless!

Comment: I achieved 40+ fps on a 2k monitor, with 4k it's around 20+ fps.

Comment: Ty for sharing! Using other methods at 1440p I got 13fps, but with mss I was able to achieve 20fps. It's fast for sure :)