# How to do a screenshot of a tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I need to do a screenshot of the content of the tkinter application below. I am on Windows 7 (or 8).

```
from Tkinter import *

def test(x):    
    #print "I'm in event:", x
    if x == 1:            # if event on entry e1 
        print 'e1 event' # do some thing
    elif x == 2:            # also if event on entry e2    
        print 'e2 event'  # do some thing else
    else: 
        print 'no event' 

def test1(x):
    test(1)

def test2(x):
    test(2)


root=Tk()
root.minsize(500,500)
e1=Entry(root)
e1.pack()

e2=Entry(root)
e2.pack()

e1.bind( "<FocusOut>", test1) 
e2.bind( "<FocusOut>", test2)   
button=Button(root, text='print').pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want some code to do that? If not you can use `Snipping Tools` which is built in Windows application. Otherwise I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are on Windows. You can use the `Win32 API` as directed in this answer [Fastest way to take a screenshot with python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows). Hope this helps.

---

But actually [Pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) should be what you are looking for.

Take the following code for example:

```
from pyscreenshot import grab

im = grab(bbox=(100, 200, 300, 400))
im.show()
```

As you can see you can use `bbox` to take screenshot that is at co-ordinates (100, 200) and has a width of 300 and a height of 400.

Also as regards the printing check out [Printing using win32api](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html). I hope these help.

Using PIL you can do a resize:

```
from PIL import Image
from pyscreenshot import grab

img = grab(bbox=(100, 200, 300, 400))

# to keep the aspect ratio
w = 300
h = 400
maxheight = 600
maxwidth = 800
ratio = min(maxwidth/width, maxheight/height)
# correct image size is not #oldsize * ratio#

# img.resize(...) returns a resized image and does not effect img unless
# you assign the return value
img = img.resize((h * ratio, width * ratio), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I would advise changing your program so that you can resize the image before printing

Comment: i used  Printing using win32api but the printed image looks like zoomed in too much and not fit all contents !!!!

Comment: so which parameter to manipulate to make printing scale fitting image contents in 'Printing using win32api' code  ?

Comment: Leave it with me for a bit I'll see what I can do

Comment: I removed these 2 lines <<<## if  bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
      bmp = bmp.rotate (90) ##>>> and made the scaled-height fixed at 6500 and it was perfect...

Answer (score 4):

I made a module that takes screenshot of **tkinter** window.

You can install with: **pip install tkcap**

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/ghanteyyy/tkcap)

**Usage:**

```py
import tkcap

cap = tkcap.CAP(master)     # master is an instance of tkinter.Tk
cap.capture(FileName)       # Capture and Save the screenshot of the tkiner window
```

Comment: Just to point out this is Windows-specific. (Which is what the OP was on as well - just adding this comment to let other Linux users know before installing).