# Tkinter : Create blur transparency

Tags: python, tkinter, transparency, blur

I am wondering how to create a blur transparency effect in tkinter. I already know how to add the transparency effect to the window by using

```
root=Tk()
root.attributes("-alpha",0.95)
```

But how can you add the blur part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This service is not provided by tkinter. However you can [take a screenshot  of your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964474/) and blur it yourself (see for instance [ImageFilter.GaussianBlur](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html) or [numpy.gaussian filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You should use ["BlurWindow"](https://pypi.org/project/BlurWindow/) package and install it this way:

> python -m pip install BlurWindow

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll

from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='green')

root.wm_attributes("-transparent", 'green')
root.geometry('500x400')

root.update()

hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
blur(hWnd)



def color(hex):
    hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    blur(hWnd,hexColor=hex)
    

e = Entry(width=9)
e.insert(0,'#12121240')

e.pack()
b = Button(text='Apply',command=lambda:[color(e.get())])
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

[image: win11]