# How to take a snapshot of a running GUI window created by Python-tkinter and save as an image file (.jpeg/.png)?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, save, root

I want to save a snapshot of my running GUI window written in Python-tkinter.

For example, saving the image of the window by a click on the "Save" button in the given code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def set_text(val):
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)
    entry.insert(0,val)
    return entry

def save_img():
    pass

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root,width=10)
entry.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root,text="animal",command=lambda:set_text("Bird"))
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(root,text="plant",command=lambda:set_text("Seed"))
b2.pack()

b3 = tk.Button(root,text="Save",command=save_img)
b3.pack(pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a screenshot of a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964345/how-to-do-a-screenshot-of-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: You can try [ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html) from `Pillow` module.

Comment: @FaresSalem
Thanks for comments but I didn't get what I wanted. 
I didn't implement the code but my understanding from your suggestions is that your solutions are taking a snapshot from the screen while what I am looking for is to take snapshot of the GUI window (regardless of its position/dimension on the screen). I am not a software developer, but since Python is generation the GUI window, there must be a way to capture that image without locating the window on the screen. Thanks!

Comment: @acw1668, please see my comment for FaresSalem.

Comment: @Adam I think you need first to locate the window, Python generates the window, yes, but it doesn't save continuously the location of the window on the screen. What saves the locations, is the [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) I think, and I don't know how to get this meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

In the `save_img` method, you can find first the coordinates of the top window then pass them to the `grab` method in the [Pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) module. How to find the coordinates?
You can start from [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm):

Methods like [winfo_x](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_x-method), [winfo_y](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_y-method), and [winfo_width](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_width-method) might help you.