# Multiple screenshots saving using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to save the multiple screenshots at a time using the tkinter in python but i am unable to append the image files into the folder. Please tell how to do this.

```
def takeScreenshot ():
    x = 1
    while x < 4:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        img.save("‪C:\Shivanshi\image\screenshot"+str(x)+".png")
        x += 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964345/how-to-do-a-screenshot-of-a-tkinter-application

Comment: Try `img.save(r"C:\Shivanshi\image\screenshot"+str(x)+".png")`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is regarding the location.
change the path to

```
r"‪C:\Shivanshi\image\screenshot"+str(x)+".png"
```

or

```
"‪C:/Shivanshi/image/screenshot"+str(x)+".png"
```