# How to capture image (screenshot) of tkinter window on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I have created a GUI app in Python tkinter for analyzing data in my laboratory. There are a number of buttons, figures, and canvas widgets. It would be helpful to take a screenshot of the entire window ('root') using just a single button that saves the filename appropriately. Example using Mac's built-in "screenshot" app [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmYla.png).

Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601374/take-screenshot-of-python-tkinter-window-not-entire-computer-screen), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964345/how-to-do-a-screenshot-of-a-tkinter-application), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image), but none worked successfully. The [final link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image) was almost successful, however the image that is saved is my computer's desktop background. My computer is a Mac, MacOS Monterey 12.0.1.

'root' is the tkinter window because

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

appears at the beginning of the script, analogous to 'window' in the example [here](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/). I'm using `PIL.ImageGrab` in the code sample below.

This is the current code, which takes an unhelpful screenshot of my desktop background,

```
def screenshot():
    # retrieve the time string to use as a filename
    file_name = root.time_string[-6:]
    full_file_name = file_name + '_summary' + '.png'
    x = root.winfo_rootx() + root.winfo_x()
    y = root.winfo_rooty() + root.winfo_y()
    x1 = x + root.winfo_width()
    y1 = y + root.winfo_height()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(full_file_name)
```

I create the button like so:

```
screenshot_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Screenshot', command=lambda: screenshot(), font=('Verdana', 24), state=DISABLED)
```

And I place the button in 'root' like this:

```
screenshot_btn.grid(row=11, column=3)
```

[This is my first post at stackoverflow. I apologize in advance if I did not follow all the guidelines perfectly on the first try. Thanks for your patience.]

Comment: What did you get by `ImageGrab.grab().save(full_file_name)` ? Do you have multiple screens ? What Python version do you run? Which version of PIL?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/134#issuecomment-567543451

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes this was exactly the problem.   I adjusted the security settings to allow PyCharm access to Screen Recording and it worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I didn't have an issue with the grab showing my desktop, but it was showing an improperly cropped image.

I have found a hacky solution. The issues appears to be with the resolution. So the dimensions need some scaling.

What I did was get the output from `ImageGrab.grab().save(full_file_name)` ( no cropping ) and measure the size of the desired image area in pixels. These dimensions will be called `x_pixels` and `y_pixels`.

Then I measured that same area on the actual window in screen units. I did this by bringing up the mac screenshot tool which shows the dimensions of an area. I then call these dimensions `x_screen` and `y_screen`. Then I modified your screenshot function as follows.

```
def screenshot():
    # retrieve the time string to use as a filename
    file_name = root.time_string[-6:]
    full_file_name = file_name + '_summary' + '.png'
    x = root.winfo_rootx()
    y = root.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x + root.winfo_width()
    y1 = y + root.winfo_height()
    x_pixels = 337
    y_pixels = 79
    x_screen = 171
    y_screen = 41
    x = x*(x_pixels/x_screen)
    y = y*(y_pixels/y_screen)
    x1 = x1*(x_pixels/x_screen)
    y1 = y1*(y_pixels/y_screen)
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(full_file_name)
```

Notice I also removed `+root.winfo_x()` and `+root.winfo_y()`

The result is shown below. It's not perfect, but I believe if I more carefully measured the pixels at the bounds of the screenshot and window the scaling would be improved.

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you @nikost .   One I figured out the main problem - giving Screen Recording permissions to PyCharm - I encountered the cropping issue you describe here.  Your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance have a "Retina" monitor? ImageGrab fails to take into account the 144 DPI image it collects from the Mac's `screencapture` command. You can compensate for this by multiplying all the x, y, x1, y1 values by 2 (but you may still miss a bit if you need to account for the Mac window titlebar).

Alternatively, use the `pyscreenshot` package (or steal its code...). It uses the "-R" option of `screencapture` to get the proper bounds for the image. Works on extended monitors like mine where the x co-ord is < 0 ('cause it's to the left of the main monitor).