# How to hide stamp added by getscreen

Tags: python, save

I am saving a drawing using getscreen, getcanvas, etc. However, getscreen() adds an intrusive stamp. How do I hide the stamp

```
tr = turtle.Turtle()
tr.color("red")
tr.forward(100)
tr.hideturtle()
ts = turtle.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="tile.eps")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib2Ka.jpg)

I've tried visible=False, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

#### The stamp is coming from TkInter, not from turtle itself

[image]

`turtle` is very dependent on TkInter.

Try this answer for useful ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65601889/7549483

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, the problem is that in the resulting image you can see a black turtle in the middle.

Then the proble is that you are using 2 turtles, the default turtle `turtle` and a second turtle you are creating with `tr = turtle.Turtle()`, this second one is the turtle you are hidding, but the default one is still visible.

If you only want to use one turtle, use the default one:

```py
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color("red")
turtle.forward(100)
ts = turtle.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="tile.eps")
```

Or if you want to use two, hide both:

```py
turtle.hideturtle()

tr = turtle.Turtle()
tr.hideturtle()
tr.color("red")
tr.forward(100)
ts = turtle.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="tile.eps")
```