# Python Screenshot application window at any size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I'm trying to get a full screenshots from an application window even when minimized, maximized, or any window shape. I've looked at other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows) but havn't found the answer that I'm looking for.

I've tried the code below and it works, but has limited capability with what I want it to do.

```
def screenshot(hwnd = None):
    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    w = right - left
    h = bot - top

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)

    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGB',
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
         bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

if result == 1:
    #PrintWindow Succeeded
    im.save(r"c:\python27\programs\check.bmp")
```

Using this code with a window that is maximized yields a great result![image]

But when the window is shrinked.......not so much

[image]

I tried editing this line but end up with an akward result :/ . `saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w+100, h+100)`[image]

Does anyone know how to take a screenshot of a fully windowed application without maximizing then windowing again? Maybe something along the lines of using `win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) + [Pillow / PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0)?

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application().start("notepad.exe")
app.Untitled_Notepad.capture_as_image().save('window.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! While pywinauto is FANTASTIC and able to do so much, that method is just a wrapper for Imagegrab from PIL which just takes a screen capture. Notepad would need to be the front foremost thing on the screen. I want to see if it's possible if it could be minimized or re-sized and still be able to capture all thats going on in the GUI.

It's not that different from using
`from PIL import ImageGrab
ImageGrab.grab((100,100,200,200)).show()`

Reference [CaptureAsImage](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/source/browse/pywinauto/controls/HwndWrapper.py?name=0.4.1)