# Screenshot a window in the background / covered

Tags: python, c++, vba, screenshot

I've been looking for a way to screenshot a window that is not on top. It's not minimized, just covered by another one which is active.
For instance, let's say I want to screenshot an online chat (window 1, not active, running in the background, not minimized) while watching a youtube video (window 2, active, showing on screen).

I'm pretty sure there are ways to do this, most of flash application keep rendering even when covered by another window.

Currently, I havn't found anything reliable.

I have been looking at C++ solutions and python ones (but I'd rather have a python one). A VBA one would be great too since I often work with macros.

I also though of creating a virtual dual screen, and assigning the window I want to screenshot to it, to have it rendering the window. But I don't know how and if it could work.

If you have any ideas, let me know :)
Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have tried a lot of simple solution and none ever succeded in screenshooting a covered window. I have mainly tried basic applications in autohotkey and autoit. I have also tried some really long and hard to understand c++ projects I found online but none did what I expected (it was just a screenshot app)

Comment: This is similar to [Fastest way to take a screenshot on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows#3586280) question.