# Python MSS Screen Capture target specific windows

Tags: python, python-mss

Is there any way to screencapture specific windows from windows handle? Even the windows is in the background it still will capture it. currently i only have this code for record the fullscreen desktop not in the specific windows.

```
def window_capture():
    # Define your Monitor
    x = 0
    y = 0
    w = 1920
    h = 1080
    
    hwnd = None

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # Part of the screen to capture
        monitor = {"left": x, "top": y, "width": w, "height": h}
        img = sct.grab(monitor)
        img = np.array(img)
    return img



while "Screen capturing":
    # Define Time
    last_time = time()

    # Get the img
    screenshot = window_capture()

    # Display the picture
    cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)

    print(f'FPS {(1 / (time() - last_time))}')

    # Press "q" to quit
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was searching for same answer as you, it looks like mss cant do that.

Possible way how to do that is with win32api.

Check this: [Fastest way to take a screenshot with python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows/3586280#3586280)

Comment: Okay thanks, btw is win32api is faster than mss ?