# What is the purpose of 'win32con.SRCCOPY'?

Tags: python, screenshot, pywin32, bitblt, win32con

In the code of answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows) question, there is a line `cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(w, h) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)`. Here what is the purpose of win32con.SRCCOPY? I have looked for documentation everywhere, but I can't find anything.

From [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__BitBlt_meth.html) I take that it is a raster operation code, but that is suppose to be an integer.  I am not sure if the documentation of BitBlt is even correct as the destination is not defined in the code, (code works fine).

I assume that SRCCOPY stands for source copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a symbolic integer constant defined in the `win32con` module that specifies what raster operation (`rop`) to perform when calling the `win32gui.BitBlt()` function.

The official [BitBlt function (wingdi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) describes it and long list of other possible argument values that can be given.

The definition for it is:

> **`SRCCOPY`** — Copies the source rectangle directly to the destination rectangle.

Here's so [Python Examples of using win32con.SRCCOPY](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/69894/win32con.SRCCOPY).