# Fastest way to get the color of a single, predetermined pixel

Tags: python, image

Currently im using python with the Pillow library

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab

px = ImageGrab.grab().load()
color = px[961, 596]
```

this works, but its quite slow, im looking for something that can run under ~50ms, i dont need it to be python, any language is fine as long as its fast.

also, im on linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to take a screenshot with python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows)

Comment: Why are you not using the `bbox` parameter?

Comment: @KellyBundy , tried it but its only a couple ms faster at 131 ms

Comment: You can try `pyautogui`, but they may be grabbing the whole screen as well.  Which operating system is this?  On WIndows, you can make a GDI call to fetch a single pixel.

Comment: Can't try it myself but that sounds surprising. How did you call it?

Comment: @KellyBundy ``` px = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(596, 961, 596, 961), xdisplay=":0").load() ``` im using the "time" shell command to time how long it takes

Comment: @TimRoberts linux, as mentioned in the post

Comment: @Narcotix So you're not measuring how long the grabbing takes but how long starting Python and importing PIL takes?

Comment: @KellyBundy wierd, i tried measuring it within the program with .time() and it says 20 ms, but when using the program there is a 130 ms delay between each fetch

Comment: Kelly asked the right question.  Do you mean in a `while True:` loop you only get 8 grabs per second, or do you mean running `python grab.py` as a one-shot you only get 8 grabs per second?