# Video Recording is too fast in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, audio, pyaudio, recording

I'm capturing my screen using OpenCV on windows. It works fine but when I try to play my captured video it plays too fast. i.e. I capture from video for 60 seconds but when I play it OpenCV recorded longer and sped up to fit the additional times content into 60 seconds of video i.e. sped up

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

time = 10
# display screen resolution, get it using pyautogui itself
SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(pyautogui.size())
# define the codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
# frames per second
fps = 30.0
# create the video write object
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))

for i in range(int(time * fps)):
    # make a screenshot
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
    frame = np.array(img)
    # convert colors from BGR to RGB
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # write the frame
    out.write(frame)

# make sure everything is closed when exited
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

I tried different fps which did not change much. Please let me know why this happens. Any answers and help welcome.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the advice, but I do not understand how to implement the solution into my script

Comment: my bad.. I didn't fully read the code. you make no attempt to wait in-between taking screenshots, so it will take them as fast as it can. You need some way to wait (like `time.sleep`) in-between capturing frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wait in-between taking screen shots. There may be a more ideal solution, but this would probably suffice:

```
from time import time, sleep
record_time = 10 #don't overwrite the function we just imported
start_time = time()
for i in range(int(record_time * fps)):
    # wait for next frame time
    next_shot = start_time + i/fps
    wait_time = next_shot - time()
    if wait_time > 0:
        sleep(wait_time)
    # make a screenshot
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    ...
```

**notes**

- `time.time`'s resolution depends on the OS. Make sure you get a number with fractional seconds. Otherwise you may need to use something like `time.perf_counter` or `time.time_ns`.
- This cannot make the loop run faster, only slower. If you can't acquire frames fast enough, the recording will last longer than `record_time` seconds, and the playback will seem "sped up". the only way to fix that is to find a faster way to acquire screenshots (like lowering resolution perhaps?).

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful, regarding the second issue, would you know how to make it forcefully finish the recording after record_time? This could help prevent longer recording times

Comment: `if time() > start_time + record_time: break`

Comment: @DigitasMerero a discussion on faster screencaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows

Comment: The absolute fastest performance would come from accessing the gpu's capture api directly, but that's way harder... (like [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/capture-sdk))