# How to force the OS to PAINT new window frames when the monitor is turned off/asleep

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm working on a WPF app.
The app takes periodic screenshots of other visible windows.
My issue is that if the monitor goes into sleep mode or the user manually turns off the monitor the other windows frame freezes.

In order to prevent that I tried using -  `SetThreadExecutionState` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate)

I use it on the apps main thread as follows -

```cs
SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
```

When the app is closed I reset it like so -

```cs
SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
```

The above seems to work, sometimes...
Tested on several machines using Windows 10/11.
On some machines it worked as intended, on others it didn't, the windows frame still froze when turning off the monitor.

Is there a guaranteed way to achieve what I'm looking for?
Just to clarify, I want the user to still be able to turn off their monitors, but I want that while the monitor is turned off new frames will still be PAINTED so my app gets an up-to-date state of those windows.

In order to reproduce what I did is - started screen recording, turning the monitor off and on manually.
Looking at the recording you can clearly see the window freezes when the monitor is turned off (on some machines regardless of the OS version)

Thanks!

Comment: Freezing in probably a problem in your code, but in the general case you can't be sure that any app will continue to be "displayed" with the monitof off (Windows is not always "painting" some apps like games scan out directly to the GPU, etc.). So it depends on what do you screenshot, and how do you take screenshots? Any reproducing code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating a hidden window that periodically requests updates from the target windows ("`RequestWindowUpdates`"). That way, even if the main monitor is off, the system still processes these requests and updates the window frames accordingly ("`RefreshWindow`").

To implement a timer in your `RefreshWindow` class for periodically requesting updates, you can use a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). This timer is suitable for WPF applications as it runs on the same thread as the WPF UI, ensuring that all timer-invoked operations are UI-safe.

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

class RefreshWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer updateTimer;

    public RefreshWindow()
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // Make window invisible

        // Initialize the timer
        updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        updateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimer_Tick;
        updateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // Set interval to 5 seconds
        updateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RequestWindowUpdates();
    }

    private void RequestWindowUpdates()
    {
        // See below
    }
}
```

To implement `RequestWindowUpdates`, you will need to interact with external windows. That typically involves using [platform invocation (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) to call native Windows API functions. However, the exact implementation can vary depending on what exactly you need to do to "refresh" these windows.

As an example, `RequestWindowUpdates` could send a simple message to the target windows to redraw themselves. That can be done using the [`RedrawWindow` function from the User32.dll library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow).

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

class RefreshWindow : Window
{
    // P/Invoke declaration for RedrawWindow
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, uint flags);

    // Constants for RedrawWindow
    private const uint RDW_INVALIDATE = 0x0001;
    private const uint RDW_ALLCHILDREN = 0x0080;

    // other parts of your RefreshWindow class 

    private void RequestWindowUpdates()
    {
        // You need to obtain handles to the windows you want to update.
        // That is just a placeholder for demonstration purposes.
        IntPtr[] windowHandles = GetTargetWindowHandles();

        foreach (IntPtr hWnd in windowHandles)
        {
            // Redraw the window and all of its child windows
            RedrawWindow(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
        }
    }

    private IntPtr[] GetTargetWindowHandles()
    {
        // Implement the logic to obtain handles of the target windows.
        // That can be done using various User32.dll functions depending on your requirements.
        // For now, returning an empty array as a placeholder.
        return new IntPtr[0];
    }
}
```

The `RedrawWindow` function updates the specified window. The flags `RDW_INVALIDATE` and `RDW_ALLCHILDREN` are used to invalidate the window and all its child windows, causing them to be redrawn.
The `GetTargetWindowHandles` method should contain the logic to obtain the handles (`IntPtr`) of the windows you wish to refresh. That can be complex, depending on how you identify these windows (e.g., by title, class name, etc.).

---

> From "[Getting screenshot via printwindow not redrawing if laptop screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974775/6309)", it seems like `RedrawWindow` won't work in the scenario I'm referencing which is turning the monitor off.

True: native windows in the WinAPI environment only redraw themselves upon receiving `WM_PAINT` messages, which they do not get if they are not visible. That includes situations where the monitor is off.

You would need to circumvent the limitations of the WinAPI windowing paradigm:

Modify the application to paint itself in a non-window context, such as a dialog box. Capture this dialog box instead of the screen.

Or: Override the `OnPaint` function in the application. Use a timer to invalidate and call the overridden `OnPaint` function periodically, as WM_PAINT messages will not be received. Draw the application to a background context bitmap. Capture the bitmap of the background context whenever needed.

Or: Run the applications in a virtual machine (VM). Since the VM handles its own display independently, it can redraw windows even when the host screen is off. Capture screenshots within the VM. That can be done either manually or programmatically.

- For VMware, refer to the [VMware Workstation Pro documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-23A52094-5237-4489-ACAA-02B587F0DE87.html).
- For Hyper-V, you can follow the guidelines outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2016/05/27/capturing-a-hyper-v-vm-screen-to-a-file/) for programmatic screenshot capture.

If you own the application code, you can directly implement the first two solutions. If not, the VM approach may be more feasible.
Redrawing to a non-window context or using a VM might introduce additional complexity and potential performance overhead.

---

> sadly I do not own the window that my app is trying to screenshot, so I can't override its `OnPaint` function.
> And running behind a VM isn't something I can ask my clients to do.
> So sadly it seems like I'm out of options because of OS limitations.

While you may not be able to directly achieve your goal due to these OS limitations, you might consider some alternatives:

- Instead of continuously capturing the screen, monitor for specific events or changes in the window state that you are interested in. That could potentially reduce the need for continuous screen capture.
- If the application's purpose allows, you could require user interaction to make sure the windows are visible when the screenshots are taken. That could be as simple as a user action that triggers the screenshot process.
- If capturing up-to-date window states is crucial for your application's functionality, you might need to inform users of the limitations. That could involve advising them to keep their monitors on or not to use certain power-saving features when using your application.
- Depending on what you are trying to achieve with these screenshots, there might be alternative ways to gather the necessary data, such as through APIs or logging provided by the applications themselves.

Comment: Hey Von, testing your suggestion now, thanks for the elaborted answer.
That being said, looking at this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974775/7210967  It seems like RedrawWindow won't work in the scenario I'm referencing which is turning the monitor off

Comment: @Ben True. I have edited the answer to include some possible alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the update, sadly I do not own the window that my app is trying to screenshot, so I can't override its OnPaint function.
And running behind a VM isn't something I can ask my clients to do.. so sadly it seems like I'm out of options because of OS limitations...

Comment: @Ben OK, I have edited the answer to propose some alternatives.