# MacOS: get screen of inactive application

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, screenshot

I am trying to get a application screenshot of another process that is in the background, after I minimise the process. Anyway I could do this?

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695214/python-screenshot-of-inactive-window-printwindow-win32gui).

But I couldn't get it to work on my Macbook, since instead of `win32gui` I am using `Quartz`, as `os.commands` for getting the screen process and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an app on your computer named Grab. It's in the Application/Utilities folder. Grab is a screenshot utility that gives you more control over what to include in a screenshot. You can take a screenshot of any window by selecting that option from Grab.